# string.split not working as intended in Firefox? Works fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome, firefox

having a bit of an issue here. I have this code:

```
//phoneNumber is a string ie ('01☂916☂5234321')
var phoneNumberSplit = phoneNumber.split('☂');

console.log(phoneNumberSplit);
//in Chrome this returns as ["01", "916", "5234321"], in Firefox this returns as
//[ "01☂916☂5234321" ]
```

I later call `phoneNumberSplit[1]` which in Chrome is fine, but in Firefox it says it's `undefined`. Why does `string.split` return two different things depending on which browser I'm in? The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) says that it works in both Firefox and Chrome. Any help?

**edit** oooook I figure out what my issue was. On the page I was testing this on the `charset="UTF-8"` was missing from the meta tag and wasn't reading the unicode character. In Chrome I guess they have UTF-8 on by default and in Firefox they do not, or something. Whoops.

Comment: What is that character you are trying to split on?

Comment: It's a little unicode umbrella, unicode U+2602. I wanted to use something it was very unlikely that it would be added to a phone number that was getting submitted.

Comment: Interesting, I'm testing in Firefox 39 and it is not working for me. Hmm..

Comment: It should be fine since it's under U+FFFF. If you go above it though (like most emojis) then you will have a problem in ES5. You can test it by doing `"some emoji here".length`, if it's 2 then it is thinking that it's two characters.

Comment: I figured out what it was, edited my original post. I forgot to decaled UTF-8 in my meta tag on the page I was testing it on, so it was unable to read Unicode characters in Firefox.

Comment: You might want to write it as an answer if you have solved the problem.

Comment: Working fine in Firefox 38.0.5

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what my issue was. On the page I was testing this on the `charset="UTF-8"` was missing from the meta tag and wasn't reading the unicode character. In Chrome I guess they have UTF-8 on by default and in Firefox they do not, or something. Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

The meta tag is required to tell the browser the character encoding. Firefox 39 did give the correct result but also a warning in the console that the character encoding was incorrect.  Try this code with the meta tag included/removed to see the difference.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>
//phoneNumber is a string ie ('01☂916☂5234321')
var phoneNumber='01☂916☂5234321';
var phoneNumberSplit = phoneNumber.split('☂');

console.log(phoneNumberSplit);
//in Chrome this returns as ["01", "916", "5234321"], in Firefox this returns as
//[ "01☂916☂5234321" ]
</script>
</html>
```